# How to add timeout to a helm chart?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which pulls a lot of images from various registries and deploys a lot of pods. It runs a lot of k8s jobs before getting the pods up.

Overall, helm install command takes huge time, so usually my helm install will also have `--timeout 3600`.

Like: `helm install --name` will also have `--timeout 3600`

Can I embed this `--timeout 1800` to the helm chat itself? (rather than providing a command line parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the timeout is a Helm option and not a Kubernetes object attribute, it can't be embedded in the chart itself.

The `--timeout` option is the amount of time the Helm utility will wait for Kubernetes commands to complete before marking the release as FAILED.

[More Info on Helm CLI options](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback)

Comment: Accepting this answer, sadly :( Hope to see a parameter in chart itself- soon!